# 403 Error with mod_rewrite & GET parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I have the following .htaccess in my application's root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&arg1=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA] # rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?controller=$1 [NC,L,QSA] # rules
```

all worked fine on my Windows development machine. I have now copied everything onto a Ubuntu server with Apache 2.4, and it's not working fine anymore.
When I use simple URLs like `/SignUp` or `/Account/Activate` everything is good. But as soon as I try to attach GET parameters (therefore the QSA) like `/Account/Activate?test=123` or `/Account/Activate/?test=123` I get a **403 Forbidden** reply from the server.

There are no entries in apache's error and access logs.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you directly enter `index.php?controller=Account&action=Activate?test=123` in address bar, does it work?

Comment: Was just about to post that: no, it doesn't work either. As soon as there is a GET parameter, the request is denied with a 403, without leaving a trace in any log. So it's an Apache issue and not my RewriteRules. Any ideas?

Comment: Should index.php be able to handle such URL? Also check PHP log, and make sure that you are looking at correct apache logs, I don't think 403 should be able to appear without a trace

Comment: Just checked with the network guys, and apparently it was the firewall that was blocking. It's working now!